# What does the "--display" option of the gnome-screenshot command do?

Tags: command-line, gnome

I am studying gnome-screenshot and I have learned about all the basic commands line options offered by the tool. But I am not able to understand the --display option. What I can understand is, the option requires some value. But, I don't know what kind of values I can enter there.

I have done quite a bit of googling, but couldn't find any help. I am using Ubuntu 16.04, bash shell version 4.3.42 and gnome-screenshot version is 3.18.0

Comment: It lets you select display (useful, when different computers and monitors are involved). See https://linux.die.net/man/1/gnome-screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `gnome-screenshot` [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gnome-screenshot):

```
--display=DISPLAY
    X display to use.
```

If you have multiple displays, you would use this to tell the program which one to screenshot, example

```
--display=HDMI-0
```

Would screenshot the screen with the display id HDMI-0.

HDMI-0 here is the id of my display, to find yours run

```
xrandr --query
```

Here is some sample output, you can see the three display ports I have, HDMI-0, VGA-0 and DVI-D-0 and if they are connect or not.

```
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.05 +  59.94*   50.00    23.97    60.00    50.04  
   1280x960      37.88  
   1280x768      17.09  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   720x576       50.00    50.08  
   720x480       59.94    60.05  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Mark Kirby , would you please tell that what is DFP-0.

Comment: Please see the update, it should be easier to understand :)

Comment: Mark Kirby, how would we get to know about our display name?

Comment: Mark Kirby, I am satisfied with your answer :)

Comment: Mark Kirby, I run the command with my display id i.e LVDS1, but it is showing some error.                                                                                --display=LVDS1                     
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: LVDS1. Please tell why it is showing this error.